# select from 2 different mysql tables

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, phpmyadmin

I have 2 tables one for products and one for images i need to get all products with its related images. and all products with only one image for each

[image]

Comment: First edit your post and make it readable. Have some respect for others before asking a question.

Comment: The question is displayed well and one knows what you are asking for, but you did not post what you have tried so far. It now looks like: "Could you write this query for me, please?"

Comment: sorry, I didn't got a good answer till the moment

Answer (score 0):

> get all products with its related images

Do a `inner join` like

```
select p.product_title,
i.*
from products p join images i on p.product_id = i.image_product;
```

> all products with only one image for each

Perform a `group by` and then `join` like

```
select p.*
from products p join (
select img_product
from images
group by img_product
having count(distinct img_product) = 1) xxx on p.product_id = xxx.img_product;
```

Comment: this returns 16 item. while i need for 2 arrays(product with all images)